# SQL-SERVER Select UPDATE OUTPUT as XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-update

Running on SQL Server 2016.

I have a routine that updates information across servers.  I want to hold a list of any changes that I have been required to make.  I am trying to output the changed columns as XML for basic storage, and would like to do this directly from the OUTPUT generated by the insert/update/delete if possible.

As an example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test
CREATE TABLE Test (myKey INT, myValue INT)
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (myKey, myValue)
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)

UPDATE  dbo.Test
SET     myValue = myValue + 10
OUTPUT  Deleted.*
,       Inserted.*
WHERE   myKey < 3

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Test
FOR     XML AUTO

DROP TABLE dbo.Test
```

I know I can set up a TVP to receive the output and then convert to XML from there, but it seems like I'm taking extra steps to do something that should be quite straight forward.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test
CREATE TABLE Test (myKey INT, myValue INT)
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (myKey, myValue)
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)

DECLARE @OutputValues AS TABLE(dMyKey INT, dMyValue INT, iMyKey INT, iMyValue INT)

UPDATE  dbo.Test
SET     myValue = myValue + 10
OUTPUT  Deleted.myKey 
,       Deleted.myValue 
,       Inserted.myKey 
,       Inserted.myValue 
        INTO    @OutputValues
WHERE   myKey < 3

SELECT  *
FROM    @OutputValues
FOR     XML AUTO

DROP TABLE dbo.Test
```

While this second piece of code does achieve the sort of output I am looking for, going via a TVP seems to be a bit wasteful.

If I can format the output from the original code directly as XML I feel that would be a better solution.  However, I can't see any way of doing so.

Many Thanks.

Comment: You cannot directly convert Output to XML. What you are doing is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? Such *monitoring / auditing* tasks are most likely better solved within a trigger...

The output clause does not allow sub-selects... The only way - not generic and rather ugly - which came into my mind was this (the clue is the *implicit cast* from `nvarchar` to `xml`):

```
CREATE TABLE Test (myKey INT, myValue INT)
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (myKey, myValue)
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)

DECLARE @OutputValues AS TABLE(dMyKey INT, dMyValue INT, iMyKey INT, iMyValue INT,Changed XML)

UPDATE  dbo.Test
SET     myValue = myValue + 10
OUTPUT  Deleted.myKey 
,       Deleted.myValue 
,       Inserted.myKey 
,       Inserted.myValue 
,       N'<root><deletedKey>' + CAST(deleted.myKey AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'</deletedKey>' + 
        N'<deletedValue>' + CAST(deleted.myValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'</deletedValue>' +
        N'<insertedKey>' + CAST(inserted.myValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'</insertedKey>' +
        N'<insertedValue>' + CAST(inserted.myValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'</insertedValue>' +
        N'</root>'
        INTO    @OutputValues
WHERE   myKey < 3

SELECT  Changed
FROM    @OutputValues

DROP TABLE dbo.Test
```

**attention**: If your values include forbidden characters (such as `<, > or &`) this will fail!

Comment: Hi Shnugo.  Thanks for this.  I'm trying to avoid the TVP all together though. I understand it may not be possible - as you said the output doesn't allow sub selects, which is the core issue I have.  I doubt there will be any way around that. Idealy I'd also prefer something a bit more generic rather than coding each column.  I also like the trigger option, especially for logs, however this is actually a cross server query (not stated in the original I appreciate) and I'm looking at holding the logs somewhere other than the clients box.  Think validating licenses and I'm sure you'll understand